# How to run function whenever call component in angular 2+?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular-components

I'm developing a angular 2+ web and have a problem. My website using lazy loading mechanism. In normal way, if I want to run function for a component whenever it's called I have to call the function in ngOnInit() but I have many component and I want always run that function whenever components called. So I wonder do we have any solution to run function without recall that function in each component  ?

Comment: Not sure if this would work, what you can do is create some base class `ParentComponent` and extend all your components from that. Call that particular method from the `ParentComponent`'s `ngOnInit()`

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you can use timer in your Main component's(Parent component) ngOnInit(). inside ngOnInit() you can check for route change.

At the first step, store the route URL.
Every seconds timer will call and check if the current route is not equal to previous one.
if the URL changed, then call the function you mentioned above.

example,

```
ngOnInit() {
this.timer = Observable.timer(1000,2000);
this.timer.subscribe((t) => {
//check current route with previous one
//if it doesn't match, call the function
});
```

}

Comment: Component need not be activated only on route change. It could be rendered as a child component based on the behavior of parent component. (ex : using `ngIf`)